# Reference request for the relation between smoothness and magnitude of Fourier coefficients

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The following statement can be found for example [in these lecture notes](http://www-m7.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/M7/Analysis/Fourier13/lecture9.pdf) (Theorem 1.7 and 1.9) with proofs but without a concrete reference:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_0 $, denote the Fourier coefficients of a function $f \in L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ by $f_k$, let $C^n$ be the set of $n$ times continuously differenciable functions. Then:

(i) $|f_k| < \frac{C}{|k|^{1+n+\epsilon}}$ for some $C,\epsilon>0$ $\Longrightarrow$ $f \in C^n$

(ii)  $f \in C^n$ $\Longrightarrow$ $|f_k| \leq \frac{C'}{|k|^n}$ with $C' = \sup_x |\tfrac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)|$

These should be pretty standard results. I have tried to find a good textbook on Fourier analysis that contains these statements, but haven't found any good reference so far. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis* by Katznelson. In the 2nd edition, statement (ii) is Theorem 4.4, and statement (i) appears  as Exercise 2 of the same section. There  is a 3rd edition now, which is substantially expanded.

Answer (score 1):

There is an exact characterization of differentiability for the $L^2$ case. This happens because $e^{inx}$ is an orthonormal basis of the selfadjoint operator $L=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dt}$ defined on the natural domain $\mathcal{D}(L)$ consisting of all periodic absolutely continuous functions $f\in L^2$ for which $f'\in L^2$. You can prove directly that $f \in L^2$ is absolutely continuous with $f'\in L^2$ iff $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}n\hat{f}(n)e^{inx} \in L^2$, which holds iff $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}n^2|\hat{f}(n)|^2 < \infty$.

Therefore,
$$
     f\in\mathcal{D}(L^s) \iff \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}n^{2s}|\hat{f}(n)|^2 < \infty,\;\;\; s=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
And $f\in \mathcal{D}(L^s)$ iff $f$ has $s-1$ continuous derivatives and $f^{(s-1)}$ is absolutely continuous with $f^{(s)}\in L^2$.

Once you get away from $L^2$, there is nothing so nice. But this is an if and only if result, which may make it useful to you.